# Processing create immediately after authenticate_user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, devise

I have a CommentsController. I allow a Guest (non-authenticated user) to see the form for posting a new comment and allow them to submit it.

Now, I wanted to authenticate my user *after* they submit the form. I've got that so far.

```
class CommentsController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!, only: [:create]

  def create
    @comment = Comment.new params[:comment]
    @comment.save!
    redirect_to @comment
  end
end
```

So now, when a user submits a comment, they're taken to the login page, and are able to authenticate. However, after they do so, the user is redirected back to the root of the application, and the comment is never created, just lost.

Now, it seems that if you call `authenticate_user!` before a GET action, after the user authenticates, they are redirected to their original destination. This doesn't seem to be the case for POST requests.

So, how do I process the `create` action immediately after the user authenticates?

Answer (score 0):

You have two possibilities here that would probably work:
1. Store the location the user is at, store it in the session and redirect them back to the form after login (which you'd probably also want to store their comment in the session so they don't have to type it again).
2. Just store the comment in the session and save it after the authentication is complete.

The Devise wiki has some information on the former of these two options available her: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-back-to-current-page-after-sign-in,-sign-out,-sign-up,-update